# How to run react js file in html file?

Tags: html, reactjs

I use npx package to create a reactjs, I want to put a connect with html file. Both file are in same level.

```
**
This is html file**
`<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script type="text-babel"></script>
  
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>`

**
This is js file**
`const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
);`
```

I refer to youtube and other methods but when I run html file, my jsx didn't display anything even npm start. The type script I tried text/jsx also cannot, and also move the first two script to head.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly connect JSX to html files because JSX is not a valid syntax, you should a transpiler like Babel or use bundlers which use Babel under the hood such as Webpack or Vite to connect your react js component to your html.

But if you must

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/babel">
    const name = 'test';
    const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```